# Making a dictionary that contains (i,i*i) where i is from 1 to n

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, numbers, range

Input Format:

> Take the number n in a single line.

Output Format:

> Print the dictionary d in a single line.

Desired behaviour, for input 8, a dictionary:

```
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64}
```

What I tried:

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    a=i*i
    print("{",i,": ",a,"}",sep="")
```

What it gives me, for input 6:

```
{1: 1}
{2: 4}
{3: 9}
{4: 16}
{5: 25}
{6: 36}
```

Comment: You are not creating a dictionary but only printing strings

Comment: If you want to print all those entries in the same line, you have to use string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the dict in a single statement:

```
d = dict((i,i*i) for i in range(1,n+1))
```

with n=8 you get

```
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the dictionary using a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
n = int(input())
d = {i: i * i for i in range(1, n + 1)}
print(d)
```

for `10` you get

```
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81, 10: 100}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print dictionary, why not just make one and keep it simple instead of making it complicated.

```
n=int(input())
d = {}
for i in range(1,n+1):
    a=i*i
    d[i] = a
print(d)
```

And you will get the expected O/P:

```
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64}
```

Answer (score 0):

## One-line solution

```
print(''.join(['{', ', '.join([': '.join((str(i), str(i * i),)) for i in range(1, n + 1)]), '}']))
```

## Explanation

There is a built-in function called `join` in `str` module. With it, you can concat a list of strings with specified seperator.

The following example

```
','.join(['Hello', 'World'])
```

will returns the concat string

```
'Hello, world'
```

You can see that `join` handles margins very well.

But please note that `join` take a single argument, list of strings. You cannot provide it with list of integers; otherwise `join` will raise an error saying:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

Thus you should force convert integers generated by `range` to strings with `str`.

## Reference

- [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)
- [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges)